# calculateroute.json giving NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED error

Tags: here-api

So when I try to call `calculateroute.json`, I'm getting a `NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED` error with no further information.

Here's my example call: `https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=<APP_ID>&app_code=<APP_CODE>&waypoint0=geo!-34.0144128,151.1121957&waypoint1=geo!-33.875455,151.207583&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&departure=2019-11-11T22:27:30`

Obviously I've removed our App ID and App Code from that call :).

```
{
    "_type": "ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType",
    "type": "ApplicationError",
    "subtype": "NoRouteFound",
    "details": "Error is NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED",
    "additionalData": [
        {
            "key": "error_code",
            "value": "NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED"
        }
    ],
    "metaInfo": {
        "timestamp": "2019-11-08T00:43:18Z",
        "mapVersion": "8.30.102.150",
        "moduleVersion": "7.2.201944-5674",
        "interfaceVersion": "2.6.74",
        "availableMapVersion": [
            "8.30.102.150"
        ]
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

I've tried looking through the docs but it seems I've done everything right and certainly it has worked for us hundreds/thousands of times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, I see the default Routing API does not find a direct route between the start and end waypoints. If you use our advanced Fleet telematics API, it does actually calculates the route.

`https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=<APP_ID>&app_code=<APP_CODE>&waypoint0=geo!-34.0144128,151.1121957&waypoint1=geo!-33.875455,151.207583&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&departure=2019-11-11T22:27:30`

Please use the advanced API if the standard API does not return results.

Comment: This did work...but why? According to the documentation it should work the other way, or am I misreading?

Comment: Our internal team is looking into the issue and will get back to you. In the mean time, please use the suggested API. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, although now the `fleet.api` method is often not working either...